# While resizing an object by script: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

When using this code, I've an error, I think it's about tuples being immutable, but I can't understand why. I'm looking to resize the cube just created:

```
# Create new cube
def create_cube(name, cornerPos, size):
    # Set cursor position for the current brick
    bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = cornerPos

    # Add a cube primitive
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

    # Get its reference via the active object, and rename
    theBrick = bpy.context.active_object
    theBrick.name = name

    # Set size        
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(scale=True)

    # Return the object
    return theBrick
```

The error message:

> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine here, maybe that's an error from a previous state in your script. It does not come from this snippet.

```
import bpy

def create_cube(name, cornerPos, size):
    # Set cursor position for the current brick
    bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = cornerPos

    # Add a cube primitive
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

    # Get its reference via the active object, and rename
    theBrick = bpy.context.active_object
    theBrick.name = name

    # Set size        
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=size)
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(scale=True)

    # Return the object
    return theBrick


create_cube("woop", (0,1,2), (1, 2, 1))
```

The error message

> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

is something you might get if you have the following code

```
>>> some_tuple = (0, 1, 2)
>>> some_tuple[2] = 4  #  <-- you can't do this in tuples
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

*tuples* are immutable, if you want to modify an individual element's value then you use a *list*.

```
>>> some_list = [0, 1, 2]
>>> some_list[2] = 4
>>> some_list
[0, 1, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. The problem wasn't actually on this line, my mistake. I'll select your answer because this may actually help someone else with this error message.